# How to Test a Spring batch Job

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to test a job but I can't get to the bottom of it, basically my step consists of a single reader and a composite Processor and a Composite writer, all this because I have to read from a single .CSV and write on MongoDB and Mysql,
here is my Job Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public  MarketDataMySqlRepository marketDataMySqlRepository;


    @Value("${file.input}")
    private String fileInput;




    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("customerInfoThreads-");
        return taskExecutor;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<MarketDataDto> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MarketDataDto>().name("ItemReader")
                .resource(new PathResource(fileInput)).delimited()
                .names("time","id", "price", "quantity", "isbuyermaker")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MarketDataDto>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(MarketDataDto.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoItemWriter<MarketDataMongo> writer(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {

        return new MongoItemWriterBuilder<MarketDataMongo>().template(mongoTemplate).collection("marketdata")
                .build();

    }
    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<MarketDataMySql> writer1() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<MarketDataMySql> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRepository(marketDataMySqlRepository);
        writer.setMethodName("save");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter CompositeItemWriter(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
        CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
        writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(writer(mongoTemplate),writer1()));
        return writer;
    }


    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessorMongo MongoProcessor() {
        return new UserItemProcessorMongo();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessorMySql MySqlProcessor() {return new UserItemProcessorMySql();}


    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor() throws Exception {
        List<ItemProcessor<MarketDataDto,MarketDataMongo>> itemProcessors = new ArrayList<>(1);
        List<ItemProcessor<MarketDataDto,MarketDataMySql>> itemProcessors1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        itemProcessors1.add(MySqlProcessor());
        itemProcessors.add(MongoProcessor());
        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();
        processor.setDelegates(itemProcessors);
        processor.setDelegates(itemProcessors1);
        //processor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return processor;

    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(FlatFileItemReader<MarketDataDto> itemReader, MongoItemWriter<MarketDataMongo> itemWriter, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate)
            throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").chunk(200000).reader(itemReader)
                .processor(compositeProcessor()).writer(CompositeItemWriter(mongoTemplate)).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Job updateUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1)
            throws Exception {

        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("updateMarketJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener).start(step1).build();
    }

    }
```

And this is my TestClass :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {BatchConfiguration.class, BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BatchConfigurationTest {


    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private MarketDataMySqlRepository marketDataMySqlRepository;




    @Test
    public void readerTest() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();

      
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());

    }
}
```

When i try to launch my test i riceive this Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'marketDataMySqlRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.aitho.springbatch.repository.MarketDataMySqlRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.aitho.springbatch.repository.MarketDataMySqlRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question in ways that make already existing answers invalid. Mahmoud gave you an answer that solved the problem you asked about. Give his answer an upvote, accept it and if you have further questions create a new question.

Comment: sorry I'm new, done, thanks

Comment: No problem Kinder maxi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you shared, you should define a bean of type `com.aitho.springbatch.repository.MarketDataMySqlRepository` in your test context.

There is an autowired field of that type in `BatchConfigurationTest` but no bean of such type is defined in your context.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i solved that problem but now another exception is thrown